# R: Computate NA with mean between, summing first and last NAs

Tags: r, data-mining, na

Consider a dataset:

```
df1 <- tibble::tribble(~Place,  ~Year,  ~Cake,  ~Coffee,    ~Tea,
"Local Cafe 1", 2022,   50, 100,    30,
"Local Cafe 1", 2021,   50, NA, 30,
"Local Cafe 1", 2020,   50, 80, NA,
"Local Cafe 1", 2019,   50, 70, 20,
"Local Cafe 1", 2018,   NA, 60, 20,
"Local Cafe 2", 2022,   60, NA, 40,
"Local Cafe 2", 2021,   NA, 50, NA,
"Local Cafe 2", 2020,   40, 40, NA,
"Local Cafe 2", 2019,   30, 30, NA,
"Local Cafe 3", 2022,   30, 40, NA,
"Local Cafe 3", 2021,   NA, NA, NA)
```

Here is the same dataset for a visual representation:

[image]

The desired actions:

1. if sum is between, then mean (example: sequence 30, NA, 40 => NA<- 35 (30+40)/2
2. If gap is more than one, then equal growth (example: sequence 30, NA, NA, 60 => 30, 40, 50, 60.
3. If NA is first (say 2021 value is 100, and 2022 - NA), then sequence if available (say, 10, 20, 30, NA => 10, 20, 30, 40; or, if there is no data for sequence, then the final value is available (example: 30, NA => 30, 30)

- If NA is last - then the same logic: (NA, 10, 20, 30 => 0, 10, 20, 30; or if NA, 20 => 20, 20

The desired output:

[image]

Orange cells - are the filled-in values.
I would be thankful for any suggestions for a nice solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could group by 'Place', apply `na.approx` (from `zoo`) on the columns 'Cake' to 'Tea' and `fill` the NAs at the end with the previous non-NA values

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Place) %>% 
   mutate(across(Cake:Tea, ~  na.approx(.x, na.rm = FALSE))) %>% 
   fill(Cake:Tea, .direction = "downup") %>% 
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 11 × 5
   Place         Year  Cake Coffee   Tea
   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Local Cafe 1  2022    50    100    30
 2 Local Cafe 1  2021    50     90    30
 3 Local Cafe 1  2020    50     80    25
 4 Local Cafe 1  2019    50     70    20
 5 Local Cafe 1  2018    50     60    20
 6 Local Cafe 2  2022    60     50    40
 7 Local Cafe 2  2021    50     50    40
 8 Local Cafe 2  2020    40     40    40
 9 Local Cafe 2  2019    30     30    40
10 Local Cafe 3  2022    30     40    NA
11 Local Cafe 3  2021    30     40    NA
```